# How to get session timeout notification in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, observers

I need to release some resources (call a C++ DLL) upon session expiration. I thought of storing an object in session and releasing the resources in its destructor. But it seems that ASP.NET Core MVC doesn't allow to store non-primitive types in session. Is there some other way to achieve this? Perhaps I can subscribe to some notification of session expiration.

Comment: Is this do you want? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/38033.asp-net-core-and-mvc-core-session-state.aspx

Comment: @LinhTuan, I need a notification in my program to arrive to some subscriber object.

Comment: If you can send a notification to some subscriber object, I think you need setup data "message" on redis cache or rabitmq, session only remembers index will get where and send to subscriber object.

Comment: @SergeRogatch did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @GlacialMan, no, I implemented a thread that checks each second for expired sessions.